# Batch file set add to text file as variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, text-files

I'm working on a school project, and I'm trying to figure out how to use a variable, output, to output to an existing text file called output.txt. Currently I am not having much luck as it either gives me a syntax error, or it just won't output the results from that command when using that variable. Basically I am trying to map the command to output the data to the existing text file, or at least the path to the text file, including the file name, to the variable. Could anyone explain to me how to do this?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: What code do you have so far?  What doesn't work?

Comment: Currently I've tried the following: <code> set /p output = < output.txt </code> <code> set output =>> output.txt </code> <code> set output = >> output.txt </code> and <code> set output = ">> output.txt" </code>, however none of them seem to be working.

Comment: Please edit your question to add your code. The way it currently is it makes it almost impossible for anyone to help you pin-point your problems.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the issue I was encountering. Apparently windows bat files will toss errors if you try to put a file name in the variable. This means that my intended solution is moot point.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is very unclear, but if I understand you correctly you want something simple like echo:

```
set output=variable you got from somewhere, just using set here as a example
echo %output% > output.txt
```

(Change > to >> if you want to append data and not overwrite the existing data)

Comment: I've edited it to be more clear, this is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

*Currently I've tried the following:  `set /p output = < output.txt`   `set output =>> output.txt`   `set output = >> output.txt`  and  `set output = ">> output.txt"` , however none of them seem to be working.*

Try escaping your carats:
`set output = ^>^> output.txt`
`echo "string to write to file with quotes" %output%`

Comment: It didn't work. The variable didn't provide any output.